# What heads can an adverbial phrase have?

Tags: syntax, english, phrase-structure

What heads can an adverbial phrase have?
Consider the following examples:

```
    I'll go to bed [soon]_AdvP.
    I'll go to bed [in an hour]_AdvP.
    I'll go to bed [when I've finished my book]_AdvP.
    I'll do it [on my own]_AdvP.
```

It is rather easy to identify the **head** of the adverbial phrase in the first example, it is `soon`. 
What is the head of the adverbial phrase in the second, third and forth example?

Is it `hour`, `finished` and `own` respectfully? 
What do you think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*in*, *when* and *on* are the syntactic heads of the respective examples. The second and the fourth example are PPs, so we can expect a preposition to appear as the head. The third example is a subordinated clause. This clause is **not** an adverb, but it rather an adjunct that is semantically interpreted as an adverbial.
Identifying the bracketed parts of the examples as "adverbials" is more a semantic decision that a syntactic one.

Comment: adverbial != adverbial phrase (AdvP or AP), I am not identifying adverbial phrases as adverbials, but I understand why you decided that preps are the heads

Answer (score 0):

Why does there have to be a category AdvP?  McCawley suggests in **The Syntactic Phenomena of English** that an adverb is a modifier of anything other than a noun (for which we have the special term "adjective").  So lets just use "adverb" in that way, as a term of convenience.  Then for your example "I'll go to bed in an hour", if the sentence structure makes "in an hour" a modifier of "go to bed", "in an hour" is an adverb, according to the definition, but its category in the sentence structure is PP (or P-bar).  If you want to reserve the term "adverb" for lexical adverbs like "immediately", we can call "in an hour" an "adverbial" instead of "adverb".

There might be a case for a category Adverb-bar, for a phrase whose head is a lexical adverb.

There is a neat characterization of "modifier" that emerges from McCawley's analyses, but which he doesn't state explicitly.  A "modifier" is something that is appended to a constituent of some category to create another constituent of the same category.  So "in an hour" will be a modifier of "go to bed", which let's say is a VP, if we assign the structure:

> [VP [VP go to bed ] [PP in an hour ] ]

"Modifier" is another term of convenience which need not be a category that turns up in sentence structure.

Added: I see that I didn't get around to answering the question.  Any head whatsoever -- that's the answer, so far as what I said above goes.  I've placed no constraint on what a modifier can be (though there might be such constraints), so anything that could be the head of something could be the head of an adverbial phrase.

Comment: Clearly the multiplication of non-terminal "categories" can go on indefinitely; but Occam shaves closely. I'm rather fond of [McCawley's](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/McCawley-Lg.pdf) "very heretical" set of X-bar categories: "`N'`, `V'`, `P'`, `A'`, `Adv'`, and `0'` (zero-bar – ‘phrasal unit whose head belongs to no part of speech’)", which also distinguished `N'` from `NP` (which is not, like `N'`, a phrase headed by an `N`, but rather is a different type, outside the X-Bar system – `NP` is the syntactic constituent type corresponding to the logical type `Argument of Predicate`).